# set ArrayAdapter vs cursorAdapter for an AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, sqlite, autocompletetextview

I have an autoCompleteTextView which i want to populate with values that are kept in a database. The number of values in the column might some day reach in thousands(according to the use).

I am unsure about the performance of the ACtextView incase I use method 1 (simpler method):

Method 1:

Define a method in the databaseHelper class which returns the values of entire column in the form of a string array. Pass the string array to the arrayAdapter. Then set this adapter to the ACtextView adapter.

Method 2:

Define a CursorAdapter class and use it to populate the results in the ACtextView. This is the link which describes this method.

[AutoCompleteTextView with CursorAdapter](http://irishandroid.blogspot.in/2011/11/autocompletetextview-backed-with-data.html)

Comment: I don't see any advantage to using method #1.  If anything, you will have to deal with the overhead of creating a large string array every time you update the database...

Answer (score 1):

if your data model is sqlite db never use ArrayAdapter, use one subclass of CursorAdapter (e. g. SimpleCursorAdapter) instead, use of ArrayAdapter is no simpler method